# In tikz length measurement from trigonometry and from coordinates differ

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I have different measurement of length with trigonometric equation using radius and theta and from coordinates. I want to solve this issue because for further computation I need to have both measurement matching.

In overleaf, a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, angles}
\title{MWE}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angleTheta{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angleThetaComplementaire{90-\angleTheta/2}
\def\r{4cm}

\pgfmathsetmacro\lengthabtrigo{2*\r*sin(\angleTheta/2)}

\path
 (0,0) coordinate [label=above left:a,inner sep=0pt] (a)
 arc [radius=\r, start angle= 90+\angleTheta/2, end angle=90-\angleTheta/2] 
 coordinate [label=above right:b,inner sep=0pt] (b); 

\pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}
\tikzmath{\lengthabcoord= sqrt(\xb*\xb +\yb*\yb);}     
\node [label=right:O,inner sep=0pt] 
        (O)      at ++(-\angleThetaComplementaire:\r) {};

\draw (a) -- (b) -- (O) -- (a);
\pic [thick, draw, above left, <->, angle eccentricity=1, angle radius=2cm] {angle=b--O--a};
\node at (1, -1.5) {$\theta$};

\node at (5,-2) {ab (from trigo)=\lengthabtrigo};
\node at (5,-3) {ab (from coord)=\lengthabcoord};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: measurement of ab]

Comment: I want both measurement of ab to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last coordinate in your code is not what you think it is. To see this, I added `\path (b);` just before `\pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}`. The reason for the discrepancy is `coordinate [label=above right:b,inner sep=0pt]` in your code, which adds the label after the coordinate. So you compare the coordinate of the label to your analytic computation. If you use the coordinate `b` instead the discrepancy goes away. (Of course, there is a tiny residual discrepancy because the accuracy of the TeX computations is not infinite.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, angles}
\title{MWE}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\angleTheta{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro\angleThetaComplementaire{90-\angleTheta/2}
\def\r{4cm}

\pgfmathsetmacro\lengthabtrigo{2*\r*sin(\angleTheta/2)}

\path
 (0,0) coordinate [label=above left:a,inner sep=0pt] (a)
 arc [radius=\r, start angle= 90+\angleTheta/2, end angle=90-\angleTheta/2] 
 coordinate [label=above right:b,inner sep=0pt] (b); 
\path(b);
\pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}
\tikzmath{\lengthabcoord= sqrt(\xb*\xb +\yb*\yb);}     
\node [label=right:O,inner sep=0pt] 
        (O)      at ++(-\angleThetaComplementaire:\r) {};

\draw (a) -- (b) -- (O) -- (a);
\pic [thick, draw, above left, <->, angle eccentricity=1, angle radius=2cm] {angle=b--O--a};
\node at (1, -1.5) {$\theta$};

\node at (5,-2) {ab (from trigo)=\lengthabtrigo};
\node at (5,-3) {ab (from coord)=\lengthabcoord};
\path  let \p1=($(b)-(a)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in (5,-4) node
 {ab (from calc)=\n1};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also added a third, IMHO somewhat more direct, way to measure the distance. The results agree (with reasonable accuracy).

Comment: as often in tikz what I took for a major issue was indeed a minor glitch :(

Comment: @theworldisnotflat Yes, the world is not flat. ;-)